# Excel. Поиск данных в изменяемом диапазоне

Tags: excel

Есть таблица полученная из программы, огромный массив, где указана дата и час (за один час выдается несколько строк), значение (число) и данные (число которое необходимо перенести в другую таблицу)
И есть таблица в которую нужно притянуть данные: столбец даты, столбец часа, а дальше много столбцов с заголовками такими же как "значение" из первой таблицы.
Для ячейки К2: Надо чтобы просматривалась таблица из программы, если дата и час совпадают с таковой во второй таблице, то искать значение (в столбце В) из шапки (в примере это 43) и если для этой даты и часа находится такое значение, то брать данные из столбца С.
Есть варианты как это сделать?
в примере должно в итоге поставиться -156. Самое простое ВПР, но как объяснить ВПРу, что надо просмотреть только диапазон для определенной даты и часа?
https://yadi.sk/i/8_-xzdX0h6Pzgg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Диапазон вычислять не нужно.

Для облегчения вычислений добавить формулу (например, в столбец `D`):

```
=A2&B2
```

Т.к. дата указана не в каждой строке, нужно ее вычислить:

```
 ПРОСМОТР(2;1/$I$2:$I2;$I$2:$I2)
```

А дальше просто: объединяем дату, час и значение:

```
дата&$J2&K$1
```

и ищем полученное в столбце D:

```
=ИНДЕКС($C$2:$C$100;ПОИСКПОЗ(ПРОСМОТР(2;1/$I$2:$I2;$I$2:$I2)&$J2&K$1;$D$2:$D$100;))
```

Если доп. формулу вместо `D` разместить в первом столбце (добавить столбец), формула несколько упростится - вместо `ИНДЕКС/ПОИСКПОЗ` данные можно тянуть с помощью `ВПР`

Comment: Спасибо! подскажите пожалуйста, как работает функция просмотр в данном случае? почему нужны именно такие параметры?

Comment: 1/$I$2:$I51 - получаем массив из 50-ти элементов - чисел (*1/значение*) и ошибок (*1/0*). Ищем в этом массиве двойку. Т.к. ее там нет, функция определит последнее положение числового значения (ошибки она игнорирует) и возвратит дату, которая находится в этой строке.

Comment: Если бы даты были записаны числом (сейчас там текстовые значения), то функция была бы проще: `ПРОСМОТР(99999;$I$2:$I2)`. Дата в десятичном выражении - 5-значное число (количество дней от 01.01.1900), а *99999* - это 13.10.2173 :)